# Exclude IPs from FQDN Resolution

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

Is there a way to EXCLUDE IPs on an interface from FQDN resulution?

Here's my use case; I have a domain joined Windows Server 2008 R2 machine that hosts multiple Web sites.  We ahve DNS A records for the various sites that resolve to different IP addresses.  I've added those IPs to the single NIC in the machine and the sites work just fine.  The problem is that the FQDN of the machine now resolves any of the IPs on the machine.  I only want the primary IP associated with the FQDN on the internal DNS servers.

Is there ANY way to accomplish this?

jon

Comment: "the FQDN of the machine now resolves [as] any of the IPs on the machine". Where are you doing the lookup from; the webserver box or the rest of the network. Either modify etc/hosts or sort out your DNS server?

Answer (score 3):

You could uncheck the option "Register this connection's addresses in DNS" in the DNS properties of the advanced TCP\IP properties of the NIC. You can then manually add only the A and PTR records for the server that you want to be resolveable via DNS.

Comment: Hmm, that might work.  Also considering adding a second NIC to the machine, setting the Web site IPs on there, and setting that adapter to not register addresses.  Just seeems like there should be a simplier way to do this.